# "There is no editor available for" Can't open .cs

Tags: c#, editor

My computer shut down while working on a project and when I opened C# again and recovered it, I got an error saying

> There is no editor available 'for filename.cs'
>   Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed

And now I can't access my code at all.

I'm using Visual C# 2010 express.

I tried opening it directly and it brings up C# but the .cs file opens up in notepad.
The file size is 30kb so it didn't get deleted.
And there is still a working .exe in the debug folder of the last run.
Is there any way to recover the code?

Comment: The code is still there. Your VS installation got corrupted somehow. Try repairing/reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: seconded; it *sounds* like your registry got fubar'd (most of the VS stuff lives in the registry). I see a VS installer in your short-term future.

Comment: I had the same exact problem with vb just now. But here, it happened with a normal Windows Form (the other Windows Forms all worked!) what the hell.

Comment: thanks to SVN for saving my 2 corrupted forms :D

Answer (score 3):

Try to open the .cs file in notepad. Then copy the code and open a new codefile and copy the code in there. That should help.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the problem you need:

1. NotePad++

And you should follow this simple steps:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Go to the Backup Folder of your VS version usually in: "C:\Users(your user name)\Documents\Visual Studio (year)\Backup Files\your project or application name".
3. Open the last Backup file of your corrupted file, usually the name format is : "Recovered-month.-day-year-time.(Your File Name).cs" with NotePad++, and copy the source code.
4. Go to your corrupted file in the project folder and open it with NotePad++, Edit => Select All => Past the source code and Save.
5. Go to windows start list and search for: "Visual Studio Tools" folder, open it and double click on: "Developer Command Prompt for VS(year)".
6. Write this two codes in the Developer Command Prompt: "devenv.exe /setup" and then "devenv /resetskippkgs" .
7. Open your project.

Note: if this didn't work for you try to do the steps before in this arrangement:

1) => 2) => 3) => 4) => 7) => 1) => 5) => 6) => 7)

and your problem will be fixed.

It works 100% for me, i hope this will helps you!

Answer (score 2):

#### I had the exact same problem happen and was able to fix it:

My issue was due to incorrect line endings / a `null` terminator was accidently introduced when I did a find / replace using Visual Studio. This threw the whole thing out of whack. My assumption would be because the Null terminator is used to signify the end of the document and I had accidently introduced it in the middle of the document (which also led to bizarre compile errors).

A simply find / replace through another editor (Notepad++) allowed me to find the incorrectly placed null terminator and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a `.cs` file in Visual Studio 2017 after a crash.
My solution was as follow:
Go to the corrupted file in Explorer. In my case the corrupted `Form1.cs` contained only NULL values due to the crash (you can test this by opening in Notepad++ for example). Just backup or delete this file. In my case there was also a backup file in the same folder named like `Form1.cs~string.TMP`. Rename this to Form1.cs and reopen your project and double click on the Form1.cs and it will open successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is full of null values like mine and there is no backup, I found a series of files with numbers on them using Recuva and the 'scan for non-deleted files' option. Among those files, I found my full forms1.cs code. I would have lost a weeks worth of work if I hadn't.

Comment: I just can't believe that this is still happening. I have VS2019 and I almost lost a work of a month. 'scan for non-deleted files' using Recuva get me back my cs file (3 days old). which is OK for me. Nothing of the above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your best option now is to repair or reinstall Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should repair or worst case scenario reinstall VS.

I will say though you might be interested in looking into some version control software so you have backups of your code. There are plenty of free options out there so it wont cost you, but this software will allow you to easily rollback if you break something, and if you do have a crash like this and loose your work you only loose the changes since the last checkin.

Answer (score 0):

C# has a "backup" folder which I wasn't aware of, but I found a backup version inside it which made me only lose a few minutes of work. =)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the .cs file again (In my case after PC crash, two notepad files opened with 
no text in it, if I try to open the .cs file with notepad++ only null separator values). Have to redo the code again.

Answer (score 0):

[Try to restore it from early date - it worked for me :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuYiR.png)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using source control(which you should) you can just undo pending changes on the corrupted file. Worked for me

Comment: Strangely, the file corrupted was not recognized as having pending changes

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was a wrong unprintable character like '' in code comments. Removing it completely solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is full of null values like mine and there is no backup, I found a series of files with numbers on them using Recuva and the 'scan for non-deleted files' option. Among those files, I found my full forms1.cs code. I would have lost a weeks worth of work if I hadn't.

was usefull and work with me thank you KDD