# My computer lost power while working on a project, how can I recover my data?

Tags: c#

I was working on a c# project on my computer when I accidentally removed the power cord.

When I started my computer back up I tried to load my project, but I got a error:

> There is no editor available for 'c\user\documents\visualstudio 2013\projects\project_name\from1.cs
>
> make sure the application for the file type(.cs) is installed

On the same project I have different forms and those still work, only `from1` is not working. The data set only contains 0's.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Either something got corrupted in your Visual Studio installation, or (more likely) the file you were working on before your computer was shut down (which I assume was `from1.cs`).

Are you able to open `from1.cs` and `from1.Designer.cs` in something like Notepad? You may want to look for NULL terminators in your file as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25125277/5101989) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976638/there-is-no-editor-available-for-cant-open-cs) *(possibly duplicate)* [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976638/there-is-no-editor-available-for-cant-open-cs).

If that doesn't work, either try copying the existing code from `from1.cs` and `from1.Designer.cs` into new files in your project, or repairing/reinstalling Visual Studio. Just make sure to make a backup of your project first, just in case! ;)

Comment: Another good reason to use version control.