# I can't get back my visual studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

in the last few days i was programing a project in visual studio express 2013. I saved it last night. Today, i cant view it properly. I can't view designer mode or view my coding. Help. When I open the project, it only shows me the files on the solution explorer, but nothing on the main screen. How can i go back to the moment where i was able to program just after i click open project? 
When i click on form1.cs and chose view designer this happens : There is no editor available for filename.cs Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed . I need help please. The code was in c#

Comment: Sounds to me like you may need to re-install Visual Studio.

Comment: Look at the file system and see if the files are there.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["There is no editor available for" Can't open .cs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976638/there-is-no-editor-available-for-cant-open-cs)