# “There is no editor available for” Can't open .cs

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My computer shut down while working on a project and when I opened C# again and recovered it, I got an error saying "There is no editor available for filename.cs Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed" And now I can't access my code at all. I'm using Visual C# 2010 express. I tried opening it directly and it brings up C# but the .cs file opens up in notepad. The file size is 30kb so it didn't get deleted. And there is still a working .exe in the debug folder of the last run. Is there any way to recover the code?

Comment: have you tried to reinstall visual studio?

Comment: Or use the repair option from the installer.

Answer (score 1):

> To fix the problem you need:
>
> NotePad++ And you should follow this simple steps:
>
> Close Visual Studio.
>
> Go to the Backup Folder of your VS version usually in: "C:\Users(your
>   user name)\Documents\Visual Studio (year)\Backup Files\your project or
>   application name".
>
> Open the last Backup file of your corrupted file, usually the name
>   format is : "Recovered-month.-day-year-time.(Your File Name).cs" with
>   NotePad++, and copy the source code.
>
> Go to your corrupted file in the project folder and open it with
>   NotePad++, Edit => Select All => Past the source code and Save.
>
> Go to windows start list and search for: "Visual Studio Tools" folder,
>   open it and double click on: "Developer Command Prompt for VS(year)".
>
> Write this two codes in the Developer Command Prompt: "devenv.exe
>   /setup" and then "devenv /resetskippkgs" .
>
> Open your project.
>
> Note: if this didn't work for you try to do the steps before in this
>   arrangement:
>
> 1) => 2) => 3) => 4) => 7) => 1) => 5) => 6) => 7)
>
> and your problem will be fixed.
>
> It works 100% for me, i hope this will helps you!

Source: ["There is no editor available for" Can't open .cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976638/there-is-no-editor-available-for-cant-open-cs)