# VS2019 C#, how to fix this: There is no editor available for

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

[image: error]

I have tried [“There is no editor available for” Can't open .cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632603/there-is-no-editor-available-for-cant-open-cs) but I cannot see backup file in my user document location.

I have open affected filename in NOTEPAD++ and found no sign of corruption in .cs file.

Suggestion anyone?

Supplemental
I have window form but F7 to inspect the code has tons of red wriggle
[image]

Comment: Do a repair of you VS?

Comment: Also, right-click file from within in VS and select `Open With` and see if you have cs editor to select

Comment: What workloads have you installed? Use the Visual Studio Installer app, choose "Modify" for your VS 2019 installation, and see what you have selected.

Comment: Go to your project directory and delete the .vs folder

Comment: Andre, I deleted the .vs and it does not fix it.

Comment: Post the raw code here, maybe there's a bad char that you ca'nt see in the file.

Comment: Morten,  have repaired the VS and it does not fix the issue.

Comment: Andre: Can I send you zipped code to you by email or other way than posting code here.

Comment: Yes, but I suggest searching for a way to hilight bad chars in notepad++. Also you can try creating a new file and pasting the relevant content, do NOT select all file! Copy small pieces at a time and paste in a new file. I believe the bad char should be at the begining of the file.

Comment: If the problem is a bad char... I'm assuming all your files are working properly and you can build your solution but this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good new, the problem went away after update release from VS2019. There no bad char as I inspected in Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in only some files (mostly *.aspx and *.Master) which even weren't edited or changed. It always occured when another developer openend the project.

What worked for me:

1. Close the editor with the opened corrupted file
2. Then open the file in Notepad++.
3. Add a empty Space somewhere. Remove empty spaces on the end of file. Save.
4. Reopen the file in Editor of VS 2019 and it will be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up about **python tools for VS 2019**, after installing and loading a project, close all .py files, then open a .py file from solution tree, after that the install will silently complete and the editor becomes available.